# Permutation test to test significance of skewness/kurtosis of two distributions?

Tags: permutation-test, skewness, kurtosis

To test the significance of the skewness difference between two distributions with $N_1$ and $N_2$ samples, would the following test work:

1. Create a single array of all the samples from both distributions.
2. Randomly shuffle the array .
3. Split the array at index $N_1$.
4. Calculate the $abs()$ of difference of the skewness/kurtosis statistics for the two partitions.
5. Repeat until desired precision/out of unique permutations.

Then check if the actual $abs()$ difference of skewness/kurtosis statistics lie beyond the $p = 0.05$ interval.

Comment: I think this would work to test whether one distribution is significantly more skew than another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this method is correct, assuming you do not care about the direction of the difference.